# How to prove this question?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

$X$ is a normed linear space. $g_1,g_2,…g_n$ are $n$ vectors in $X$, I want to prove that for any $x\in X$,
$\exists\ \alpha_1^0,…\alpha_n^0,$
$$\left\|x-\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i^og_i \right\|=\inf_{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n} \left\|x-\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_ig_i \right\|$$
$\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n$ are random real numbers.

Comment: what does $\alpha_i^0$ mean?

Comment: @JonesY they are real numbers that satisfy the equality.we want to prove that they are exist.

Comment: @JonesY the $0$ is a superscript, not a power.

Comment: @Aweygan i think he/she knows that. and also, exponents ARE notationally superscripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is essentially a finite dimensional problem.

Without loss of generality, we can assume that the $g_k$ are linearly independent.

Define a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $\|\alpha\|_* = \|\sum_k \alpha_k g_k \|$. Since all norms
on finite dimensional spaces are equivalent, we have
$\|\alpha\|_* \ge c \| \alpha \|_2$ for some $c >0$.

Let $\phi(\alpha) = \|x-\sum_k \alpha_k g_k \|$. It is easy to check that $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

Then $\phi(\alpha) \ge \|\sum_k \alpha_k g_k \| - \|x\| \ge c \| \alpha \|_2 - \|x\|$, and if $\| \alpha\|_2 > {2 \over c} \|x\|$, then 
$\phi(\alpha) > \|x\|$.

Hence $\inf_\alpha  \phi(\alpha) = \inf_{\alpha \in \overline{B(0,{2 \over c} \|x\|) } } \phi(\alpha)$.

Since $\overline{B(0,{2 \over c} \|x\|) } $ is compact, there is some $\alpha^*$ such that $\phi(\alpha^*) = \inf_\alpha  \phi(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the finite dimensional subspace $Y$ spanned by the vectors $\{g_1,g_2,\ldots, g_n\}$, then $0\in Y$, so
$$
d(x,Y) \leq \|x\|
$$
so consider the set
$$
B := \{y\in Y : \|x-y\| \leq \|x\|\}
$$
Check that this is a closed bounded set, which is compact since $Y$ is finite dimensional. The function
$$
y \mapsto \|x-y\|
$$
is continuous on $B$, and so it attains its minimum. This is what you want.